# Matplotlib: Making a histogram with string data

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, histogram

I have data which shows orders per day of the week. I want to plot a histogram. This is my code:

```
hist1 = df_final['day_of_week'].plot.hist(bins = 7)
hist1.title('Orders per Day of the Week')
hist1.xlabel('Day of the Week')
hist1.ylabel('Orders')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
```

It returns the error "TypeError: no numeric data to plot". How can I fix this?

Comment: To be more precise, the column "day_of_week" contains string data (Monday, Tuesday, etc.)

Comment: You seem to want a bar plot with counts: `df_final.groupby("day_of_week").size().plot.bar()`

Comment: Oooh..yes, that looks nice :) THANKS!